# SBJSON parsing issue with large JSON file

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to parse a rather large json file, and I am beginning to have a bit of an issue

An example of what the JSON looks like is this

```
{
"info":"info",
"products":[
            {
            "name":"HomeScreen",
            "screens":[
                       {
                       "name":"View Details",
                       "id":1,
                       "title":{
                       "name":"Default_Name",
                       "number":"Default_Number"
                       },
                       "widgets":[
                                  {
                                  "id":8,
                                  "splits":[
                                            {
                                            "control":{
                                            "type":1,
                                            "limitLow":0,
                                            "limitHigh":100
                                            },
                                            "texts":[
                                                     {
                                                     "value":"blah",
                                                     "style":{
                                                     "size":10,
                                                     "colour":"#FFFFFF"
                                                     },
                                                     "test1":"asd",
                                                     "test2":"zxc"
                                                     }
                                                     ]
                                            }
                                            ]
                                  },
```

And so on

I want to be able to parse the texts values and place them in an object. I have the class created, but I am unable to retrieve the exact values. I have tried doing the following

```
   NSArray *test = [MainJSON valueForKeyPath:@"products.screens.widgets.splits.texts"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in test){

    NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"value"]);
}
```

It prints out the values but with loads of brackets as well, and I need to be able to get the exact value from the JSON. I also tried doing

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [test count]; i++){

    for(NSDictionary *dict in [test objectAtIndex:i]){

        NSLog(@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"value"]);
    }

}
```

But same problem. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. I have tried soo many different solutions, but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance

EDIT Output for example I gave is

```
2012-03-21 12:12:18.731 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
    (
            (
                    (
            "CURRENT BALANCE",
            "[var:UnbilledAmount]"
        )
    ),
            (
                    (
            "THE BILL IS DUE IN",
            "[var:DaysToBill] DAYS"
        )
    ),
            (
                    (
            TEXTS,
            "[var:UsedTexts] of [var:MaxTexts]"
        ),
                    (
            DATA,
            "[var:UsedData] of [var:MaxData]"
        ),
                    (
            TEXTS,
            "[var:UsedMinutes] of [var:MaxMinutes]"
        )
    )
)
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.732 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    )
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.732 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    )
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.733 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    )
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.733 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    )
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.734 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    )
)
2012-03-21 12:12:18.734 JSONObjects[4467:f803] (
        (
    )
)
```

As you can see a lot of brackets which is deeply frustrating.

Edit2:

Test is an array of NSDictionary objects though, here is the code

```
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"json" ofType:@"json"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *MainJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *test = [MainJSON valueForKeyPath:@"products.screens.widgets.splits.texts"];
```

Edit:

I have been able to get a single value using this code

```
 for(NSDictionary *dict in [textArray objectAtIndex:0]){

 NSLog(@"%@", [[[[dict valueForKey:@"value"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]);
 }
```

However this is a bit messy.

Comment: Please add your output to the question - I suspect that the 'loads of brackets as well' are because it's outputting an array instead of the value you expect :)

Comment: And what happens if you put `NSLog(@"%@", [[dict objectForKey:@"value"] class]);` to see if the object is a string or something else?

Comment: Added output to the example I gave. Also I tried that code you gave me, it causes it to crash saying "-[__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a37310
"

Comment: That tells me that `test` isn't an array of `NSDictionary` objects, it's an array of `NSArray`s.

Comment: Test is an array of NSDictionay objects, though, see edit for the code I have used

Comment: How does your code prove that test is an array of dictionaries? All it does is prove that test is an array of whatever the JSON happens to tell it to be.

Comment: I am not sure I understand properly. I make a dictionary of the JSON, then I make an array of that dictionary of text values. What I am I missing then?

Comment: You don't _make_ a `NSDictionary` - you ask the JSON to be parsed and _assume_ that it's a `NSDictionary`. You then ask `MainJSON` for the value of 'products.screens.widgets.splits.texts', which you _assume_ is an `NSArray`. How do you know that test is an array of dictionaries, not an array of arrays? What does `NSLog(@"%@", test.lastObject.class);` output (this will tell you the type of object in your test array)?

Comment: It prints out

2012-03-23 11:12:41.509 JSONObjects[2585:f803] (null)
2012-03-23 11:12:41.510 JSONObjects[2585:f803] __NSArrayI

Comment: Then it's not an array of NSDictionaries, it's an array of NSArrays. Can I recommend changing JSON library - this one seems very complicated to use - I would use SBJOSN instead. (http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Comment: I have downloaded that framework but there are practically no tutorials online that show you how to parse a large JSON file, so it makes it very difficult to use. Would you be able to point in the direction of a tutorial that actually shows how it is used properly?

Comment: Exactly as you use your other framework - `NSArray *myArray = [jsonString JSONValue];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. In the products Object class, I didn't add in an NSDictionary object into the class object. As I needed to make a dictionary of the screens. Then loop through that dictionary, find the widgets, then create a dictionary of that array, find the splits, then make a dictionary of that  array, and then loop through that and so on until I got to texts. Now it works perfectly! :D